# Access objects using variable name powershell

Tags: powershell

I am unable to access my object using `.PropertyName`.

I have tried using `$val.Options.$propertyName` but it yields no result.

`$propertyName` is a value input from a file

```
`$val.$propertyName` results in "Cannot index into null array"

$result = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.ArrayList';
        foreach ($user in $users) {
            $val = Get-LocalUser $user | Select *
            $val = $val.$propertyName
            $result.Add($val)
        }
```

Comment: In addition to [JPBlanc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68656526/15339544), note that there is no performance advantage of adding to an `ArrayList` vs just doing `$result = foreach ($user in $users) { Get-LocalUser $user | Select *  }`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an arraylist at all. Just let PowerShell do the collecting by capturing the output inside the loop

```
$result = foreach ($user in $users) {
    (Get-LocalUser $user).$propertyName
}
```

<sup>This is assuming your variable `$propertyName` contains a valid attribute name</sup>

---

While the above code does what you've asked for, I don't think the result would be very helpful, because it just lists whatever is in the property stored in `$propertyName`, and you cannot see which user has what values in there.
A better approach would be to output **objects** with the properties you want returned.

Something like

```
# just an example..
$propertyName = 'Description'
$users        = 'WDAGUtilityAccount', 'Administrator'
$result = foreach ($user in $users) {
    output an object with the name of the user, and also the property you are after
    Get-LocalUser $user | Select-Object Name, $propertyName
}

$result
```

Since parameter `-Name` (the first positional parameter) can take an array of usernames, this can be shortened to:

```
$result = Get-LocalUser $users | Select-Object Name, $propertyName
```

Answer (score 1):

In your context $val.$propertyName does't mean anything can you try :

```
$result = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.ArrayList';
        foreach ($user in $users) {
            $val = Get-LocalUser $user
            $result.Add($val)
        }
```

$result will be an array of "Localuser".